# Casting from void* to struct

Tags: c, struct, void-pointers

I am passing data of type struct Person to a linked list, so each node's data pointer points to a struct Person.

```
struct Person {
char name[16];
char text[24];
};
```

I am trying to traverse the list and print the name/text in each node by calling

```
traverse(&list, &print);
```

Prototype for traverse is:

```
void traverseList(struct List *list, void (*f)(void *));
```

List is defined as:

```
struct List {
struct Node *head;
};
```

My print function accepts a void * data :

```
print(void *data) { .... }
```

I know I have to cast the data to struct Person, correct?

```
struct Person *person = (struct Person *)data;
printf("%s", person->name);
```

I know this is not sufficient since I am getting an "initialization from incompatible pointer type" warning. How can I successfully cast a void* in this case? Thank you.

Comment: What is prototype of `traverse`? And which type is `list`?

Comment: You may want to check on how you are passing the list to traverse, and how you are actually using print.  Everything you showed seems to match up.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk I've edited my question to include those.

Comment: @user1889966 is your `print` declared as is, or returning `void`? If it is declared without return, it is probably `int`

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk I apologize for not including that, it is declared as static void.

Comment: "initialization from incompatible pointer type" makes no sense for the line `struct Person *person = (struct Person *)data;`, since a) `void*` is compatible with every object pointer type, b) you explicitly cast.

Comment: @user1889966 The code seems correct for C. You need to add more code from `traverse` and `print`

Comment: See my answer for a link to a working example incorporating the code you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem's not with the cast, or even with the way you're passing the function around. The problem is that your declaration of `print` is missing a return type, in which case `int` is usually assumed. The compiler is complaining because you're passing an `int (*)(void*)` to a function that's expecting a `void (*)(void*)`.

It's easy to fix: simply add `void` in front of your `print` function declaration. See:

https://gist.github.com/ods94065/5178095

Answer (score 1):

> My print function accepts a void * data

I would say, rewrite your `print` function by accepting `struct Person *` .

Comment: Why would that matter? In C `void*` is compatible with any non-const pointer to structure.

Comment: Just because no need to cast then.

Comment: You'd still need to cast - you'd need to cast from `void (*)(struct Person*)` to `void (*)(void*)` when passing the function to traverse. I suspect that's less portably safe, and IMO it's less elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Your traverseList function accepts a function pointer (which takes a void pointer), but it doesn't accept an argument for that void data. It seems that this is what you're after:

```
void print (void* data)
{
    printf("%s", ((struct Person*)data)->name);
}

void traverseList (struct List *list, void(*f)(void*), void* data)
{
    f(data);
}
```

Then you can call traverseList:

```
traverseList (&list, &print, &person);
```

Comment: I'd think the argument that `traverse` supplies to `print` is the `data` member of the `struct List *` argument of `traverse` resp. the later nodes in the list.